# how to start and stop a function based on the mail

Tags: outlook, autoit

Is there any way to start a function once I receive an email and run for every one hour and stop when an email is received to stop.

This is the code with which im trying. here i can start the function and execute in each time interval but cannot stop as it stuck within the loop and not recognizing the stop email.

Healthcheck is the function i want to execute for every one hour. here i have given time interval as 2 mins.

```
HotKeySet("+!e", "_Exit") ;Shift-Alt-E to Exit the script
MsgBox(64, "ERS Health check", "Hotkey to exit the script: 'Shift-Alt-E'!")

Global $oOApp = ObjCreate("Outlook.Application")
Global $test = ObjEvent($oOApp, "oOApp_")

While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

; Outlook 2007 - NewMailEx event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147646%28v=office.12%29.aspx
Func oOApp_NewMailEx($sOL_EntryId)

    Local $oOL_Item = $oOApp.Session.GetItemFromID($sOL_EntryId, Default)
    MsgBox(64, "OutlookEX UDF Example Script", "New mail has arrived!" & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
            "From:    " & $oOL_Item.SenderName & @CRLF & _
            "Subject: " & $oOL_Item.Subject)

            If $oOL_Item.Subject = "Stop" Then
               Exit
            EndIf

    While $oOL_Item.Subject = "Start"
     HealthCheck()
     Sleep(120000)

     WEnd
EndFunc
```

Comment: when a new mail received to the outlook the Objevent calls the function that starts with "oOApp_" Global $test = ObjEvent($oOApp, "oOApp_")

Answer (score 0):

I'm still quite new to this (working with applications like Outlook), so I might have missed something, but the following seems to work:

```
HotKeySet("+!e", "_Exit") ;Shift-Alt-E to Exit the script
MsgBox(64, "ERS Health check", "Hotkey to exit the script: 'Shift-Alt-E'!")

Global $oOApp = ObjCreate("Outlook.Application")
Global $test = ObjEvent($oOApp, "oOApp_")
Global $Status = "undefined"

While True
    Switch $Status
        Case "Start"
            HealthCheck()
        Case "Stop"
            ConsoleWrite(@HOUR & ":" & @MIN & " StopMail received. Exiting." & @CRLF)
            Exit
        Case Else
            ; do nothing
    EndSwitch
    Sleep(100)
WEnd


; Outlook 2007 - NewMailEx event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147646%28v=office.12%29.aspx
Func oOApp_NewMailEx($sOL_EntryId)
    Local $oOL_Item = $oOApp.Session.GetItemFromID($sOL_EntryId, Default)
;~  MsgBox(64, "OutlookEX UDF Example Script", "New mail has arrived!" & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
;~          "From:    " & $oOL_Item.SenderName & @CRLF & _
;~          "Subject: " & $oOL_Item.Subject)

    $Status = $oOL_Item.Subject
EndFunc   ;==>oOApp_NewMailEx


Func _Exit()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>_Exit

Func HealthCheck()
    Local Static $htimer
    If TimerDiff($htimer) < 120000 Then Return ; not enough time passed since last run
    $htimer = TimerInit()
    ConsoleWrite(@HOUR & ":" & @MIN & " HealthCheck." & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>HealthCheck
```